# Laravel livewire: How would you implement equivalent to Vue's v-if v-else

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to write my first examples using LiveWire, I want to do something as simple as...

```
<div v-if="active">
    Active things
</div>
<div v-else>
    Inactive things
</div>

<button @click="toggle" type="button">toggle</button>
```

I have built my example component with `php artisan make:livewire sample`, in the

sample.blade.php:

```
<div>
  <div wire:model="active">
    Active things
  </div>
  <div wire:model="!active">
    Inactive things
  </div>
</div>

<button wire:click="toggle">toggle</button>
```

The component I only added:

```
public $active=true;

public function toggle() {
    $this->active = !$this->active;
}
```

Of course, it doesn't work. I could use normal blade's directives, but my main interest in Livewire is to be able to change the DOM without reloading the page.

What would be the equivalent?

Comment: Have you tried `@if($active) active @else disabled @endif` ?

Comment: Nope... as inside the class?

Comment: thats the point of Livewire.  You use blade.  If $active changes then the view partial is re-rendered changing that part of the page

Comment: Sure, it was so obvious it hurts. I was thnking it should be more like Vue... I've been all morning trying to figure how to do this

Comment: There's also a `wire:click="$toggle('normal')"`, which let's you exclude the method and just toggle that property directly. Although your code toggles a different property than what you're checking, I'm guessing that's just a copy/paste error

Comment: Correct, I'll edit that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply doing like this

```
{{-- Don t forget to alway wrap the component in a div --}}
<div>

  <div>
    @if($active) Active @else Inactive @endif things
  </div>

  <button wire:click="toggle">toggle</button>

</div>
```

Comment: This was so obvious i feel so stupid even asking this. I was thinking in Vue type, not blade. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes , I tend to lose track of simple blade functionality. One has to remember that Livewire extends Blade, it doesn't replace anything Blade does